# Swipe/Scroll android screen element to specific coordinates in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, testing, automation, appium

I am automating an android app.I want to take screenshot of the screen in android app by placing an element to a specific coordinate by scrolling/swiping. How can I do so??

Answer (score 0):

use below code will help you :

```
driver.find_element_by_android_uiautomator('new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true).instance(0)).scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().textContains("**/Put some text of scroll screen/**").instance(0))')

driver.save_screenshot("screenshot.png")
```

below is my sample code to scroll & take screenshot, I am facing any issue:

```
from appium import webdriver

class test123():
    desired_caps = {}
    desired_caps['platformName'] = 'Android'
    desired_caps['platformVersion'] = '4.4.2'
    desired_caps['deviceName'] = 'XXXXXX'
    desired_caps['appPackage'] = 'net.one97.paytm'
    desired_caps['appActivity'] = 'net.one97.paytm.AJRJarvisSplash'
    driver = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps)
    driver.implicitly_wait(1000)

    driver.find_element_by_id('net.one97.paytm:id/edit_no').send_keys("9999990088")
    driver.find_element_by_id('net.one97.paytm:id/lyt_mob_op').click()

    driver.find_element_by_android_uiautomator(
        'new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true).instance(0)).scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().textContains("Vodafone").instance(0))').click()

    driver.save_screenshot("screenshot.png")
```

Comment: UiScrollable and UiSelector cannot be resolved. How to??

Comment: which version of appium you are using

Comment: appium 1.4.13.1

Comment: I am using 1.4.16.1   can you paste the error you are getting

Comment: Thnx for the input, but i needed in java.

Comment: Thnx, the code is similar in java as well. Found it.

Comment: Please make sure to tag the language while asking question